# Maven only invokable from terminal while root

Tags: command-line, bash, java, compiling, maven-3

I'm following the directions laid out here:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/installing-maven-304-ubuntu

Everything is in the right place and the sym link is working correctly.

However whenever I try to call mvn from the terminal, I get:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:~/Desktop$ mvn   
The program 'mvn' can be found in the following packages:   
 * maven   
 * maven2   
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

But if I switch to root, then it works fine:

```
sudo su

root@xyz-laptop:/home/xyz/Desktop# mvn  
[INFO] Scanning for projects...   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------   
[INFO] Total time: 0.079 s   
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-30T18:11:54-07:00   
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/234M   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm very sure this is an issue with permissions but I don't know what to set the folders permissions to as I've never hit this error before. This error is frustrating me as well:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:/usr/local$ cd apache-maven-3.2.2/   
bash: cd: apache-maven-3.2.2/: Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you install your program using `sudo` or `su -` ? Using `su -` will log you as root, so that may be where your problem lie. Concerning the permission, try using `sudo -R 777 /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.2/` (you might want to tweak the 777 if you are not the only user). That will allow you to access the folder as a regular user. Then, edit your `~/.bashrc` and add the alias `alias mvn='/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn'`

Comment: I did not use SU to install. I unpackaged the tar file and sudo cp to copy it to /usr/local. Your advice worked! Thanks! Small typo though I think you meant sudo chmod -R :D

Comment: Yes of course ;) glad it worked for you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First need to grand ownership of the folder to myself:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.2/
```

Then I opened ~/.bash_aliases with:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_aliases
```

And I added:

```
alias mvn='/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn
```

Thanks to @Ploutox for the right commands and I also did a bit of editing / corrections myself.

Comment: The 777 permissions are way too permissive for this scenario. This makes every file in `/usr/local/apache-maven-3.2.2/` both world writable (i.e. everyone can write them) and executable. Consider using 644 for all files and 755 for directories and files that are intended to be run.

Comment: do you need the alias if the mvn folder is in your path?

Comment: Short answer: no. 

I wrote this a very long time ago but I'll try to help! If you type `which mvn` it should output the directory of the executable that will be executed if you type in `mvn`. 

If you get nothing back you can either add `mvn` to your path or you can create an alias. Both might achieve similar functionality when executing in a bash terminal but have different implications. 

If something is on your path - that means other things can find it more easily.

If something is an alias that just makes it easier for you to execute on command as needed in a terminal.